# How i can upgrade magento version without ssh from 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

when i am trying with magento connect its showing following

Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Ext 1.7.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_LinLibertineFont 2.8.14.1, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.1,
Already installed: community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Credis 1.8.0.0, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.1.0, skipping

Comment: At this point you cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just replace the default magento files ant it solved
Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that package dependencies are broken on your installation and require manual resolution.
I'd suggest to hire Magento professional familiar with upgrades and capable to perform it smoothly. If your store is in production, I'd would not do any upgrade actions based on advices as it is hardly possible to predict all possible issues and suggest a correct upgrade path here. If your store is not in production, you may consider to do just a clean install of latest version to save your time.